# load caption and link into clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Is there a cross platform way to copy a link and caption to the clipboard, ie so google.com appears as 'Google' when pasted, but is a clickable link.

When copying Spotify URLs this works.

Preferrably this can be executed in JS.

Answer (score 1):

there is no javascript for cross browser implementation of clipboard functionality, you can try flash based plugin which is cross browser, even HTML5 support for clipboard is also not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Today, the solution would be to use [zeroclipboard](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard) (Github uses it).

It is explained [here](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#text-to-copy) how to set the text that will be copied.

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("copy-button"))
clip.on('dataRequested', function(client, args)
{
  client.setText( "Copy me!" );
});
```